# python - point system in a 2 player game

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, if-statement

I am having trouble computing the point system as desired. The way it works is if both players get the same answer for a question, 2 point is added to an empty list and skip over the next answers.

Point system works this way: 1 point is added to the list when a pair doesn't match-- and on the next pair if it finds 'deal' and 'deal' add -2 to the empty list, and move on to next pair. Else if 'no deal' and 'no deal' is in the pair add 0 to the empty list, and move on to next. Otherwise if these instances don't match add -1 to the list and move on to the next.

My question is how do I get the ***if else statement*** to check these conditions written, because I am not getting the expected result.

Please, help and apologies if this isn't clear.

```
# list of answers from the 2 players
player1 = ['yes', 'deal', 'yes', 'no deal', 'no', 'deal', 'yes', 'deal'] 
player2 = ['yes', 'no deal', 'no', 'deal', 'yes', 'deal', 'yes', 'deal']

pairs = zip(player1, player2)
points = [] #points are placed in here
for a, b in pairs:
    if a != b: #if pair doesn't match 1 point is added to the list
        points.append(1)
        next(pairs, True) #this makes it go to the next pair without skipping over
        if a == 'deal' and b == 'deal':
            points.append(-2)
            break
        elif a == 'no deal' and b == 'no deal':
            points.append(0)
            break     
        else:
            points.append(-1)
    else:
        a == b #if a pair is matched 2 point is added to the empty list
        points.append(2)
        next(pairs, None) #this skips over the next pair
       
print(count)
```

here's the code with the fixed workflow and the code checks each condition as it should and the appropriate points to a list. Thanks for your help @Aru

````
pairs = zip(player1, player2)
points = [] #points are placed in here
for a, b in pairs:
    
    if a=="deal" and b=="deal":
        points.append(-2)

    elif a=="no deal" and b == "no deal":
        points.append(0)

    elif a!=b and a!= "deal" and a!="no deal":
        points.append(1)

    elif a==b:
        points.append(2)
        next(pairs, None)

    else:
        points.append(-1)

print(points)```
````

Comment: The built-in function [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) retrieves the next item but it won't jump to the next loop iteration. That's what `continue` is for.

Comment: @JanWilamowski where in the code would you add `continue` because it still doesn't behave as it should. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if i understood your question correctly.
Maybe you should just breakdown your question to the most important things, you dont have to describe the steps of your code, we see the code.

```
player1 = ['yes', 'deal', 'yes', 'no deal', 'no', 'deal', 'yes', 'deal'] 
player2 = ['yes', 'no deal', 'no', 'deal', 'yes', 'deal', 'yes', 'deal']

pairs = zip(player1, player2)
points = [] #points are placed in here
for a, b in pairs:
    
    if a=="deal" and b=="deal":
        points.append(-2)

    elif a=="no deal" and b == "no deal":
        points.append(0)

    elif a!=b and a!= "deal" and a!="no deal":
        points.append(1)

    elif a==b:
        points.append(2)

    else:
        points.append(-1)

print(points)
```

If this gives you the expected output, your control flow was incorrect.
Maybe running code in this environment step by step http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display
can help you more.

Comment: thank you for referring to pythontutor as it did help figure it out. My control was indeed incorrect.  I added the `next(pairs, None)` method to your correction and it prompts the for loop jump over the next instance after every 2 appending. Thanks again!

Comment: you are welcome, feel free to mark it as accepted answer or give it an upvote :) or edit your question and type in your solution below your old code.